# Change ViewController Elements when CollectionView Item is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, segue

So i want to do following:

If ANY item in the Collection View is selected, the ViewController automatically changes all Elements in the ViewController for the pressed item. The Code looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(indexPath.item)
{
    GlobaleDetailAnsicht *GDA;
    GDA.DetailBild.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[ZellenBilder objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GlobaleDetailAnsicht" sender:self];
}
return YES;
}
```

Just like a "Global Detail Page". But it won't change the Image and also not when i try it with labels. I guess it doesn't get the item number of the pressed item. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you try to reload the content?

Comment: No haven't tried it yet. Is there a function for that?

Comment: Yes, [collectionView reloadData];

Comment: Nope doesn't work for me. But thanks

Comment: You define GDA but you don't instantiate it.  It will be nil.

Comment: already made it higher in the programm

Comment: i would still need some help here :(

Comment: Even if you have a class property entitled GDA, the locally defined copy will override it.  Is GDA the view controller you are segueing to?